# Pixma MX860 Printer - making horrid grinding noise

Tags: printing, printer

I have a pixma mx860 printer and something isn't right. I printed something a couple days ago and the font color was supposed to be black, but came out green and blurry. Then, the next time I try to print something, it makes a long grinding noise, then error message 5c00 comes up. I followed the maintenance instructions, but nothing happened.

Then I observe a little lever looking gear in the far right of the printer making the noise, right after the print head goes into self cleaning. The gear is way in there, so I can't really tell if there's something stuck in it without taking apart the printer.

I know it's not the print head because it's at the opposite side of the printer from where the noise is coming from. My guess is the waste absorber is jammed. Also the print head cleaner instead of cleaning the print head, it just smears ink all over it.

Can anybody help me fix this?

Comment: unless there is a printer expert that knows that printer REALLY well and can predict exactly what the problem is without looking at it, you're probably looking at getting a new printer.

Comment: The printhead cleaner is just an absorbent sponge, of course it'll be smeared with ink. This question is also off-topic as it doesn't involve a computer at all.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Actually, I checked the meta questions, and they say printer questions are on topic.

Comment: Even if they are on topic, I really doubt anyone is going to answer your question, sorry brother.

Comment: I agree with @Sickest. While I would love to have an answer for you, I think [this image](http://www.nathanjamail.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/car-noise-price-list.jpg) sums up quite well the issue with diagnosing mechanical hardware by a description of the sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, I find it's the printers purge unit that isn't working. I guess I have to take the printer apart (how fun) and find out what's wrong. Apparently, all 5c errors are related to the purge unit. Well, time for a long project! Now, how to get the thing apart...